# How to set gray level on matlab imshow(I,n)?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I'm quite new to the MATLAB and I've noticed that old versions of MATLAB used to have the `imshow` command allowing a second argument to set how many levels of gray that can appear at the output (in case of a gray image) and it was something like:: `imshow(imagematrix,4)` to show only 4 levels (shades) of gray of `imagematrix`.

I'm using Matlab R2014a and this command doesn't exist anymore. I couldn't find an alternative, and the error message I get is below:

```
The syntax IMSHOW(I,N) has been removed.
```

How can I set how many levels a grayscale image will be displayed with `imshow` or an alternative?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using [`histeq`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/histeq.html) instead, which not only performs a histogram equalization in order to contrast enhance your image, but you can also specify how many levels the output can be visualized at.  Think of this as `imshow(I,n)` but with an added bonus of contrast enhancing your image... so you can do something like:

```
out = histeq(I, n);
imshow(out);
```

For example, using `cameraman.tif` that's part of the MATLAB system path and specifying `n = 4`, the original image looks like:

[image]

The output looks like:

[image]

To check the total number of unique intensities in the image, we can do:

```
>> unique(out(:))

ans =

    0
   85
  170
  255
```